# Dumb pass-through HTTPS reverse proxy

Tags: apache-http-server, proxy, https

My origin server has HTTPS working properly and it uses ACME (Let's Encrypt). I would like to set up a reverse proxy that will also accept HTTPS requests and forward them to the origin server. Then I will update DNS to the proxy.

In the end, the client will understand that the proxy is actually the web server. And I will be free to hide the actual location of the origin web server wherever I want to.

Is it possible to achieve this using Apache and .htaccess? Is it possible to achieve this without the HTTPS certificates being on the proxy?

Comment: It is possible to configure Apache as reverse proxy. It is impossible to impersonate a web server without the private key of the destination site. Should I put this as an answer? Because it looks like a simple yes/no question and that is the answer.

Comment: @techraf Thank you, yes this is an answer. You CAN impersonate a webserver by simply forwarding traffic at the IP layer. I just want to know if that setup is possible with Apache somehow.

Comment: Port forwarding is not the same as reverse proxy.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Apache needs to terminate SSL to reverse proxy.

If you have a single server to which you want to send all HTTPS requests you can simply port forward port 443 to the appropriate server. How to do that depends on the OS on your front server and instructions should be easily found on the internet.

If you have different servers to forward to depending on the hostname in the request, you can use something like [haproxy](http://blog.haproxy.com/2012/04/13/enhanced-ssl-load-balancing-with-server-name-indication-sni-tls-extension/), which will use the SNI extension to decide to which server to forward to. If the client doesn't support SNI (modern browsers all support it but Wikipedia has a [SNI support list](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication#Support)), you will have to decide on a default server to send to, which has a single certificate valid for all possible domains served by the front server (or decide that you won't support those clients).